# replace URLs but not images using a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$str = ':-:casperon.png:-: google.com www.yahoo.com :-:sample.jpg:-: http://stackoverflow.com';
```

and I need to replace urls from the `$str`, but not images like `casperon.png`.

I have tried the following regex for replacing urls.

```
$regex  = '/((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/';
$str =  preg_replace_callback( $regex, 'replace_url', $str);
```

and the php function like below.

```
function replace_url($m){
  $link = $name = $m[0];
  if ( empty( $m[1] ) ) {
    $link = "http://".$link;
  }
  return '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'.$name.'</a>';
}
```

But it replaced the image as links. But I need the image as normal.Only the urls need to replace. So I put the images in between `:-:image:-:` the symbols. Can anyone help me..?

Comment: You need to identify what it is about the images that enables you to identify them as images (clue: the extension), and then write a regular expression that will ignore any text strings ending with those extensions. I would remove the `:-:` because they're not really helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
:-:.*?:-:\W*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?:http|ftp|https)://)?[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lR8fZ3/2)

This regex works on the concept of first selecting the unwanted text betweem `:-:` and `:-:` and **discarding it** using `(*SKIP)(*F)` directives.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code like that, using filter_var to check the possible urls:

```
function replace_url($m){
    $link = (empty($m[1])) ? 'http://' . $m[0] : $m[0];
    if (!filter_var($link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
        return $m[0];
    return '<a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' . $m[0] . '</a>';
}


$regex  = '~((?:https?|ftp)://)?[\w-]+(?>\.[\w-]+)+(?>[.,]*(?>[\w@?^=%/\~+#;-]+|&(?:amp;)?)+)*~';
$str =  preg_replace_callback( $regex, 'replace_url', $str);
```

Comment: This works for me and I think this is the efficient way for my work.

Comment: @Casperon: Note that my answer is a more general way to do it, but for your specific case anubhava answer may be more appropriate.